# NgMap directive showing fusion table remove some data

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

So I have recently switched to using an open-source directive called ngMap that takes care of a lot of the work for generating Google Maps for me.

I previously had a Google Map showing on the about page, and when I changed everything over to use Angular views this broke. So I got everything back so that now it has the visual aspects I wanted. Although things aren't like they worked when simply using the base Google Api.

Before it is asked I am aware that in the new example there is a style option attached to my map. If you remove that in the directive it just displays PA.

For example:
Old Map

```
<script>
    function Init() {

        console.log("I loaded.");

        google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
        var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
          (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
        if (isMobile) {
            var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
            viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
        }
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');

        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.878100, -77.799600),
            zoom: 7,
            draggable: !("ontouchend" in document)
        });
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            map: map,
            heatmap: { enabled: false },
            query: {
                select: "col4",
                from: "1kDOtIvEE7OkCmPb_vPXluY0ZOjBD4lvyMICDSRMl",
                where: ""
            },
            options: {
                styleId: 6,
                templateId: 137
            }
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function () {
            map.setCenter(center);
        });

        var center;
        function calculateCenter() {
            center = new google.maps.LatLng(40.878100, -77.799600);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function () {
            calculateCenter();
        });


        if (isMobile) {
            var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
            var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
            var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
            legend.style.display = 'none';
            legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
            legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
            legendOpenButton.onclick = function () {
                legend.style.display = 'block';
                legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
            }
            legendCloseButton.onclick = function () {
                legend.style.display = 'none';
                legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

With this kind of output:
[Link to see desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQH0m.png)

New Map:

```
<ng-map zoom="6" center="40.878100, -77.799600">
                        <fusion-tables-layer query="{
    select: 'geometry',
    from: '1kDOtIvEE7OkCmPb_vPXluY0ZOjBD4lvyMICDSRMl'}" ,
                                             styles="[{
                                             polygonOptions {
                                             fillColor '#00FF00' ,
                                             fillOpacity 0.3
                                             }]">
                        </fusion-tables-layer>
                    </ng-map>
```

With Undesired output:
[Image of undesired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P35WE.png)

Answer (score 0):

The specified style is not getting applied since there is a typo in `styles` attribute, the valid value is:

```
styles="[{
             polygonOptions: {
                 fillColor: '#00FF00' ,
                 fillOpacity: 0.3
         }  
}]"
```

**Example**

```js
angular.module('map-app', ['ngMap'])
    .controller('map-controller', ['NgMap',
        function (NgMap) {
           
        }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>

<div ng-app="map-app" ng-controller="map-controller">
  <ng-map center="40.878100, -77.799600" zoom="6">

    <fusion-tables-layer query="{select: 'geometry',
    from: '1kDOtIvEE7OkCmPb_vPXluY0ZOjBD4lvyMICDSRMl'}" , styles="[{
                                               polygonOptions: {
                                                  fillColor: '#00FF00' ,
                                                  fillOpacity: 0.3
                                               }  
                                             }]">
    </fusion-tables-layer>

  </ng-map>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you help me remove the information that gets displayed when a user clicks a county? I want to display my own custom data that is loaded from a database via Angular and Json.